# Calling factory function from controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I want to call a function from factory inside controller in angularjs. I'm doing a simple blog application. My server-side is written in django-rest, and now i need to implement its client side.

Factory:

```
    angular.module('blog').factory('$postservice', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return{
        post : function (val) {
            console.log(val);
            return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/' + val + '/:id');
       }
    }
}]);
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('blog')       
    .controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','$postservice', function($scope,$postservice){
        $scope.postList = $postservice.post('post');
        console.log(this.postList);


    }]);
```

if i check console "val" is correctly passing to post(name is irrelevant, it will change) function.

I've made a html file for showing post list. I can not see correct output in that html. I have 9posts in my db, but 6 post is shown(I understand it from number of divs created), and i also have a bug in this point. i can not reach any property of post with

```
{{post.<property-name>}}
```

This creates empty field.

Note: "val" value is for making generic service. I want to use it as "post", "category", "user" etc...

My question is how to solve this problem without changing my factory structure ? (I want to keep "val" value in factory)

Comment: it would return data after promise gets resolve..you probably need to use `.then`